# WSO2. Call Web Service in AbstractApplicationAuthenticator Inherited

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

> I have a maven project with an authenticator from AbstractApplicationAuthenticator, and I call a endpoint webservice
>   with javax.xml.wsjavax.xml.ws.Service and Dispatch
>   dispatch.
>       In maven pom I use org.apache.felix maven-bundle-plugin. But, first time I have error

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
```

> I append dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-saaj</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And then the error is:
    `javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found`

> I append dependencies of cxf in `</Import-Package>`, but it doesnt
>   Works. Any suggestions?